# How to push array to another array correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

When I run the following:

```js
var months = new Set(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]);
var string = "27 - 28 August 663 CE";
var words = string.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
    words[i] += " ";
}
var array = words;
array = $.map(array, function(value){
  return value.replace(/ /g, '');
});
const dates = {
    days : [], 
    months : [],
    years : [],
    suffixes : []
}
for (const word of words) {
    if (months.has(word)) {
        dates.months.push(word);
    } else if (+word < 32) {
        dates.days.push(+word);
    } else if (+word < 2200) {
        dates.years.push(+word);
    } else if (/\w+/.test(word)) {
        dates.suffixes.push(word);
    }
}

console.log(array);
console.log(dates);
```

The output is incorrect:

```
Object {days: Array(2), months: Array(0), years: Array(1), suffixes: Array(2)}
```

While if I run:

```js
var months = new Set(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]);
var words = ["27","-","28","August","663","CE"];
const dates = {
    days : [], 
    months : [],
    years : [],
    suffixes : []
}
for (const word of words) {
    if (months.has(word)) {
        dates.months.push(word);
    } else if (+word < 32) {
        dates.days.push(+word);
    } else if (+word < 2200) {
        dates.years.push(+word);
    } else if (/\w+/.test(word)) {
        dates.suffixes.push(word);
    }
}

console.log(dates);
```

The output is correct:

```
Object {days: Array(2), months: Array(1), years: Array(1), suffixes: Array(1)}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/753/)

Comment: Youre not pushing an array.

Comment: I am not getting what are you looking for.

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht the output of the first code should be correct as per the output of the second code

Comment: @Jonasw hey man, what do you mean I am not pushing an array? `words` is an array pushing into the array `dates'

Comment: What does this supposed to do?: `words[i] += " ";`

Comment: @rob.m and do you do dates.months.push(words) somewhere?

Comment: change this for (const word of words)  by this for (const word of array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause youre adding a whitespace in your first code, which is completely unneccessary:

```
words[i] += " ";
```

And cause of that

```
"january "
```

isnt found in the array (or Set), as it only contains:

```
"january"
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought.

Comment: Ok yeah just tried and works, will accept. Thanks. But why is it adding white space to months if I am doing it on words? That's why that map bit to remove white spaces, I didn't think that space was being added to months

Comment: @rob.m youre adding it to words. But because of that the word isnt found in the months set, so months.has(word) is false.

Comment: what about this then `array = $.map(array, function(value){
  return value.replace(/ /g, '');
});` means it isn't working right?

Comment: @rob.m it is working. Array doesnt contain the whitespace youve added right before. However words does and were talking about words here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are using the "words" array even "array", and it has withe spaces.
This [demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/z3fqzyjh/) give expected result:

```
var string = "27 - 28 August 663 CE";
var months = new Set(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]);
var words = string.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
    words[i] += " ";
}
const dates = {
    days : [], 
    months : [],
    years : [],
    suffixes : []
};
var array = words;
array = array.map(array, function(value){
  return value.replace(/ /g, '');
});
console.log(array, 'array');
console.log(words);
for (word of array) {
    if (months.has(word)) {
        dates.months.push(word);
    } else if (+word < 32) {
        dates.days.push(+word);
    } else if (+word < 2200) {
        dates.years.push(+word);
    } else if (/\w+/.test(word)) {
        dates.suffixes.push(word);
    }
}
console.log(dates);
```

Comment: No need for jQuery... `array = array.map(word => word.replace(/ /g, '') )`, job done